# Test view model with WCF service calls

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, unit-testing, nunit

I want to unit test my view model which makes wcf service calls.

My view model:

```
public class FooViewModel : Screen
{
    private IService service;

    public FooViewModel(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        service.LoadThisAndThat((o,e) => 
        {
            //Fill collections and so on
        });
    }
}
```

My service client interface:

```
public interface IService
{
    void LoadThisAndThat(EventHandler<ThisAndThatCompletedArgs> callback);
}
```

This is implemented by a class which uses the actual generated service client proxy to make the call.

My question is: How can I unit test, that my view model does the service call and fills my collections with returned data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [Sheridan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18482600/2382536) - what are you trying to test?

- The network connection?
- The service frameworking (e.g. WCF)?
- The .NET implementation of threads?

I'm guessing that all you are really interested in is how your view model responds to the data it is provided by the service.   Let us slightly re-factor your code to make this more transparent (all we have really done it to remove the `EventHandler` delegate from the signature of the service method):

```
public class FooViewModel : Screen
{
    private IService service;

    public FooViewModel(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => service.GetResult())
            .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    //Fill collections and so on
                });
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    Result GetResult();
}
```

Does this answer your question?  No!

Even if you were to mock out the implementation of `IService`, the .NET implementation of threads does not guarantee anything about when the call to `service.GetResult()` will run, or when the results will be returned back to view model.  However - are we interested in testing the .NET threading implementation?  I guess not.

If you are dedicated to testing, then you have to consider the tests as first-class consumers of your code.  To this end we have to modify our code to make it more amenable for testing.  Take two is below:

```
public class FooViewModel : Screen
{
    private IService service;

    public FooViewModel(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void Load(bool runAync = true)
    {
        if (runAync)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => service.GetResult())
                .ContinueWith(t => SetResults(t.Result));
        else SetResults(service.GetResult());
    }

    private void SetResults(Result result)
    {
        //Fill collections and so on 
    }
}
```

Here we have introduced a boolean parameter to the `Load()` method, which will default to `true`.  During testing, we call it with `false` to ensure the results are dealt with synchronously and our view model is behaving as we would expect with the data returned.

If you don't like the addition of the extra parameter, you could just make the `SetResults` method public, and treat that as your initialization step during testing.

The takeaway is that we shouldn't be afraid to make changes to the public implementation to accommodate testing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement a method that returns some data in your `TestService` class. The purpose is *not* to test whether the WCF service works, but to test how the view model works. As such, we create a situation which `appears` as if the service is working perfectly... we simply return the required data, but without needing to call the *actual* service which is one of the main things that we are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that the callback is called asynchronously.
the callback pattern is outdated, use Task !
you can do

```
public Task<int> Load()
{
     TaskCompletionSource<int> source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
     service.LoadThisAndThat((o,e) => 
     {
          //Fill collections and so on
          source.SetResult(e.Count);
     });
     return source.Task;
}
```

so that in your test you could do (synchronously)

```
public void test()
{
    var result=Load().Result;
}
```

Tasks are good for many many things !